# How to add the decimal point based on the condition in oracle?

Tags: sql, plsql

```
select case when country='USA' then to_number(value,10,3) else to_number(Value,10,2) from emp_country;
```

Table Creation:

create table emp_country
(
PersonID int,
Country varchar(25),
Value number(30,5)
);

### current output:

### personid    country value

### 12           USA    123.45

### 13           INR    125.09

### 14           USA    234.09

### 15           UK     123.45

---

### Expected output:

### personid    country value

### 12           USA    12.345

### 13           INR    125.09

### 14           USA    23.409

### 15           UK     123.45

TO_char is not working and getting error like **ORA-01722: invalid number , getting the error**

Comment: What are you going to do with the results? What datatype has your column? Couldn't you just use `TO_CHAR` like this?: https://dbfiddle.uk/1jJQfzKF

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number , getting the error

Comment: As said, you need to provide more details, for example the create table command.

Comment: To_char(val, decode(ctry,'usa', '0999.999', '0999.99')

Comment: Table Creation:
create table emp_country
 (
    PersonID int,
    Country varchar(25),
    Value number(30,5)
 );



current output:

personid country value

12 USA 123.45
13 INR 125.09
14 USA 234.09
15 UK 123.45